# Incompatibility type when using range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to to run a command if these arguments checks , but it's giving me incompatibily type on that block, what am I doing wrong?

```
Dim rn as range

For Each rg In Columns("X")
        If rg.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(rg.Row, "U").Value) = "Demande de création d'intervention" _
           And LCase(Cells(rg.Row, "V").Value) <> "envoyé" Then
```

Comment: Is it a typo, `Dim rn as Range`, not `Dim rg as Range`? (Also, I'd shorten the range instead of checking every single cell in a column)

Comment: Debugging hint: Check what `rg` is after `For Each rg In Columns("X")`. It is the whole column. So `rg.Value` throws that error. You mean `For Each rg In Columns("X").Cells`. But multiple other problems with your code, see @BruceWayne's comment. And `LCase(Cells(rg.Row, "U").Value) = "D..."` will never be true as `D` is not lower case.

Answer (score 0):

### Comparing Strings

- If you loop through the cells of the whole column, it will take forever. Calculate the last row, the row of the last non-empty cell in the column, instead.
- `LCase(Something)` will never be equal to `Demande...`. Use `demande...` instead.
- If you use `CStr` to convert a value to a string, you won't have to worry about the value being incompatible when comparing it to another string.

[image]

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
    
'    If LastRow < FirstRow Then
'        MsgBox "No data in column.", vbCritical
'        Exit Sub
'    End If
    
    ' Reference the column range ('rg').
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, "X"), ws.Cells(LastRow, "X"))
    
    ' Reference the other column ranges ('rg2', 'rg3')
    Dim rg2 As Range: Set rg2 = rg.EntireRow.Columns("U")
    Dim rg3 As Range: Set rg3 = rg.EntireRow.Columns("V")
    
    ' Note that all three ranges are of the same size.
    
    ' Declare additional variables to be use in the loop.
    Dim Cell As Range ' Current cell in the first range
    Dim cString As String ' String Representation of the Current Cell's Value
    Dim r As Long ' Index of the Current Cell
    
    ' Use 'CStr' to convert the values to strings to avoid an error occurring
    ' if the cell contains an error value.
    
    For Each Cell In rg.Cells ' note '.Cells'
        r = r + 1 ' count the cells (in this case rows)
        cString = CStr(Cell.Value)
        If cString Like "?*@?*.?*" _
                And LCase(CStr(rg2.Cells(r).Value)) _
                    = "demande de création d'intervention" _
                And LCase(CStr(rg3.Cells(r).Value)) <> "envoyé" Then
            ' Do your thing, e.g.
            Debug.Print r, cString
        End If
    Next Cell
 
End Sub
```

**Results in the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).**

```
 8            FY@I.NV
 11           MF@X.UT
 14           EU@X.IF
```